# Pyplot hist() with multiple NaNs causes incorrect binning

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am in the process of creating histograms for a large dataset which may contain several NaN values. However, I've found that when I don't remove the NaNs from the data, the data gets binned incorrectly. If I run the following code:

```
nan_list = [1, 1, 2, np.nan, 2, 3, 3]
h = plt.hist(nan_list, bins=range(5))
print h
```

I get back the following histogram:

```
(array([0, 2, 1, 0]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), <a list of 4 Patch objects>)
```

Now, this seems reasonable, as it just skips everything after the first NaN. However, if I add another NaN to the list, so that it becomes:

```
[1, 1, 2, np.nan, 2, 3, np.nan, 3]
```

I get back the following result:

```
(array([0, 2, 3, 1]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), <a list of 4 Patch objects>)
```

In this case, it places three items in the [2, 3) bin, even though I only have two values in that range. It also only places one value in the [3, 4) range. What could be the reasoning for this odd binning?

By the way, I am aware that I can just remove the NaNs from the data to obtain a correct histogram. I am simply wondering why this odd behavior occurs.

Comment: What versions of `numpy` and `matplotlib` are you using?  I can't reproduce either of your results -- I get `(array([ 0.,  2.,  2.,  2.]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), <a list of 4 Patch objects>)` for both, but I'm using development versions.

Comment: Just for what it's worth, I get the same results as DSM with matplotlib 1.2 and 1.3 (though that's with numpy v1.7.1 on both, which is likely where the difference is coming from).

Comment: I'm using numpy 1.3 and matplotlib 0.99.1.1. I suppose the out-of-date software could be the reason for the bugs.